# Nest JS: Cannot read properties of undefined in repository in test

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs, typeorm

I'm facing an issue where I cannot read the repository during my test. Seems like the repository is not getting injected during test. Below are the code I used:

ads.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Ads]),
    ProfilesModule,
  ],
  providers: [AdsService],
  controllers: [AdsController],
  exports: [AdsService],
})
export class AdsModule {}
```

profile.module.ts

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Profiles]),
  ],
  providers: [ProfilesService],
  controllers: [ProfilesController],
  exports: [ProfilesService],
})
export class ProfilesModule {}
```

ads.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class AdsService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Ads) private adsRepository: Repository<Ads>,
    private profileService: ProfilesService,
  ) {}

  create = async (createAdsDto: AdsDto) => {
    const profile = await this.profileService.findByProfileId(
      createAdsDto.profileId,
    ); 

    return null;
  }
}
```

profiles.service.ts

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProfilesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Profiles) private profileRepository: Repository<Profiles>
  ) {}

  findByProfileId = async (id: number): Promise<Profiles> => {
    // below line is failing
    const profile = await this.profileRepository.findOne({
      where: { id },
      relations: { user: true, avatar: true },
    });

    return profile;
  };
}
```

ads.service.spec.ts

```js
describe('AdsService', () => {
  let service: AdsService;
  let adsRepository: Repository<Ads>;
  let profileRepository: Repository<Profiles>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AdsService,
        { 
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Ads), 
          useClass: Repository 
        },
        ProfilesService,
        { 
          provide: getRepositoryToken(Profiles), 
          useClass: Repository 
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    service = module.get(AdsService);
    adsRepository = module.get<Repository<Ads>>(getRepositoryToken(Ads));
    profileRepository = module.get<Repository<Profiles>>(
      getRepositoryToken(Profiles),
    );
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  describe('Initial variables must be defined', () => {
    test('Ads Service must be defined', () => {
      expect(service).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('Ads Repository must be defined', () => {
      expect(adsRepository).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('Profile Repository must be defined', () => {
      expect(profileRepository).toBeDefined();
    });

    test('can create ads', async () => {
      const ads = await service.create({
        profileId: 1,
        type: 'Oferta',
        category: 'Vivienda',
        location: 'Alicante',
        title: 'Apartment For Rent',
        description: 'This is a sample description',
        extract: 'This is a sample extract short description',
      } as AdsDto);
    });
  });
});
```

It is failing on profile service. Seems like it cannot inject the repository during test. Here is the screenshot of test result:

[image]

Comment: what if you change that arrow function class field to a standard function?

Comment: @MicaelLevi tried to make it like this **async findByProfileId(id: number): Promise<Profiles> { .... }**. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to mock the repository, or use a real one? In unit tests you usually want to mock it. I'll describe both cases.

#### Mocked Repo

For mocked Repository, create a mock object first:

```js
export const createRepositoryMock = (): Repository => {
  const repositoryMock = <Repository>Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Repository.prototype).reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x] = jest.fn();
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return repositoryMock;
};
```

Then in the test file use the mock object.

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  let repo: Repository<Ads>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(Ads), useValue: createRepositoryMock() },
      ],
    });
  });
  repo = app.get<Repository<Ads>>(getRepositoryToken(Ads));
});
```

This way you mocked all the functions with `jest.fn()`, and can now use them with `jest.spyOn()` to create your own implementation.

```
describe('test repo', () => {
  it('tests find function', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(repo, 'findOne').mockResolvedValueOnce({ a: 123, b: 'c' });
    console.log(repo.findOne());
  });
});
```

#### Working Repo

You have to add TypeOrmModule.forRoot to the test module.

```js
describe('Test', () => {
  let repo: Repository<Ads>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const app: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot()],
      providers: [
        { provide: getRepositoryToken(Ads), useValue: Repository<Ads> },
      ],
    });
  });
  repo = app.get<Repository<Ads>>(getRepositoryToken(Ads));
});
```